# How to send hidden data

Tags: html, forms, hidden

I have a form(like the one below for example) where I type data, but  I also want to send  data which are  not  directly entered by the user, for example a generic Id(for a user in this case)

```
<form name="input" action="" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="user">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Don't know if I have been  clear enough, I hope so.

Comment: Use input `hidden`: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_hidden.asp

Comment: also before answering a question

Answer (score 59, accepted):

try a `hidden` input:

```
<input type="hidden" value="foo" name="user_id" />
```

The user can't see it, but remember that such inputs can be spoofed and need to be validated on the server just like any other input.

Comment: Be careful because the form does not send the hidden input or any input unless the tag contains the name field